# Authentication from asp.net app to api, Oauth

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, asp.net-identity

For the sake of understanding this I'm using a sample app from [asp.net](https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api)
and when I run it and use the sample page they have, everything works great.

Then I create a new empty asp.net project with mvc scaffolding enabled, and I recreate the scenario with 2 different layers. I'm able to register by using this form action:

```
    <form method="post" action="https://localhost:44305/api/Account/Register">
        <h3>Register</h3>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { id = "txtUserName", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { id = "txtPassword", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Confirm Password</label>
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { id = "txtConfirmPassword", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Register</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

but when I try to Login it redirects to the same page with username/password I entered as query strings: (http://localhost:57972/?Email=username&Password=password)

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Email</label>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { id = "txtloginUserName", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Password</label>
            @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { id = "txtloginPassword", @class = "form-control" })
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button id="btnLogin" class="btn btn-default">Log In</button>
        </div>
<script>
    var token = "";
    $('#btnLogin').click(function () {
        var username = $('#txtloginUserName').val();
        var password = $('#txtloginPassword').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:26812/Token',
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
            data: {
                grant_type: 'password',
                username: username,
                password: password
            },
            success: function (data) {
                token = data.access_token;
            }
        })
    });
</script>
```

** Update

I realized I had to call the full url for /Token and now when I log in and watch the network packet it responds with a 200 OK status code, but then pops up an error in console:
"No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:57972' is therefore not allowed access."

I've added config.EnableCors() into my webapiconfig, and I've added the annotation on my apicontroller to allow all for testing purposes:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers:"*", methods:"*")]
```

[image: Picture of the network response and error:]

Comment: Confirming is `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` error from the pre-flight `OPTIONS` request, Right ?

Comment: The odd part is the POST request itself returns OK then it throws that error, but in the log I only see the one request and it is the POST.

Comment: There are numerous question around `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with MVC API, I had my share of trouble getting them in order. It's good that you don't have this in the OPTIONS. Try setting the `datatype` of the ajax request to `dataType: "jsonp"` and see if you still have this issue.

Comment: When I change it to jsonp it turns the request into a GET and throws a different error? I installed PostMan and with the IIS express running I try sending the same request there and it fails with unsupported_grant_type. So it's making me think my call is fine but the server needs something changed to accept it? It's literally the default microsoft web api auto generated project with CORS added.

Comment: Sorry i should have mentioned that `jsonp` is only for cross domain  `POST`. Unsupported grant type is token post error. Make sure ur cred are in the  post body with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`.

Comment: Added the content type to the ajax call, and also went ahead and posted a snip of the request/error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this method to your Global.asax :

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization, Authentication");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "86400");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
        }
        else
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        }
    }
```